# using SCP for active/port type connection?

Tags: ubuntu, scp

I need to transfer files from `remote FTP server` to my unix server. Usually, I transfer using:

```
scp -r 'remote@x.x.x.x:"/remote-path"' '/local'
```

the problem now is that this server uses [ACTIVE](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/ftp_modes) and I think that's the reason why SCP is not backing up the files. To be honest I am not familiar with `ACTIVE` type connection and I cannot find anything in the [manual](https://linux.die.net/man/1/scp) about this type of connection.

Is it possible to use SCP to transfer files on `ACTIVE` FTP?

Comment: Normal FTP or SFTP server? You can use ftp command to get files from remote ftp server.

Comment: @supriady normal FTP. I did not know that there's a FTP command-line?

Comment: Actually you can install ftp package on unix server.So you can run ftp  ip address of ftp server.Remember to set type of file between ASCII or Binary when you get files from ftp server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`scp` and `ftp` are two [different protocols](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/differences-between-scp-and-ftp-704023/). If you have ssh access to the server, it doesn't matter what mode `ftp` is. Just use `scp` as you normally would.

If you don't have `ssh` access, the answer is **no**, you cannot use `scp` if you don't have access via `ssh` to the remote machine.

Comment: but I do not have `ssh` access to the remote server, only `FTP` access

Comment: It was not  fair judgement in this QA site..I didnt think users knew the answer and posted it here.I am trying to understand how this QA site voted the question and the answer correctly.

Comment: @supriady we take all kinds of questions, from beginner level to expert. If you want to see some of the more interesting questions, try http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=votes or a search like http://unix.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=is%3aA%20score%3a10

Comment: New user posted the question also got a minus vote.I joined many open source forum.They always asked more detail information and didnt judge user's question.Some users didnt know how to ask smart question.Users got a smart answer too.Sorry I joined this QA site less than a month.

Comment: @supriady I'm not sure what else you expect in this answer—The Wolf seems to have thought sftp and ftp are the same thing, and maulinglawns let him/her know they're different. The Wolf considers that an answer to his/her question. Of course, if you have more to add, you can to add your own answer. (Side note: I'm pretty sure English isn't your first language, and it's a bit difficult for me to figure out what you're saying.)

Comment: Sorry,I can;t say it's a smart answer.The Wolf didnt say anything about the answer.The Wolf said dont have ssh on remote ftp server.I didnt think the answer was helpful for users.I am techical guy.I wrote simple English.I am not Novelist.I cant write a page of article.

Comment: @supriady The check mark next to the answer can only be set by the person who asked the question. It means "this answered my question". So The Wolf has said (by checking the box) that this answered his question.